# FastReports in delphi 10.3

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I'm trying to install FastReport in Delphi Rio 10.3 but is not working. On the recompile wizard of FastReport when I compile appears the following:

> F2613 Unit 'FMX.frxDCtrl' not found. dclFMXfrx26.dpk not compiled!
>   delphi26 error: FMXfrxe26.dpk(3) Fatal: E2225 Never-build package
>   'FMXfrxe26' must be recompiled (15177) [] dclFMXfrxe26.dpk not
>   compiled! Done

And when I try to start Delphi it can't load the FastReports components.
Someone know why this is happing and how to solve. Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Do you have the FastReports source? If so, contact FR directly for support. If not, you should not be trying to recompile it at all, because you can't recompile without having the source code available for compiling.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I don't belive that I have the source, I'm trying to install the trial version, but even if a I don't recompile I get a error when open Delphi: It's not possible to locate the entry point of the procedure @System@Classes@TFieldsCache@$bcctr$qqrv on the library of dynamic link C:\Windows\System32\FMXfrx26.bpl

Comment: Where are you getting the trial version from? It does not come with source, so you can't recmopile it - it's a trial. The full (purchased) version includes source and can be recompiled. Where you're getting the triial installation is relevant - if you're installing from GetIt package manager, you should be opening a support ticket with Embarcadero. If you got it by downloading from FastReports directly, you can contact them for help. The error in your last comment (the entry point one) sounds like you had another version installed and didn't remoce it before installing the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall FR FMX, install it again, don't run recompile.esx, move all pas files from LibD26 folder to another folder, run reconpile.exe with "Run as administrator" option and recompile all FR's packages